# SQL query for related rows of data from the same table

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I am trying to understand how to write SQL statements which can return related rows of data from the same table.

By way of example, I have the following table called purchases:

```
------------------------------
|ID | Customer | Date | Cost | 
------------------------------
 1  |   1      | Mon  | 20.0 
 2  |   1      | Tue  | 10.0 
 3  |   1      | Sat  | 23.0 
 4  |   2      | Thu  | 211.0 
 5  |   2      | Mon  | 24.0 
 6  |   2      | Sat  | 50.0 
 7  |   3      | Mon  | 34.0 
 8  |   3      | Sat  | 200.0 
 9  |   3      | Fri  | 90.0
```

I want the data for how much each customer spent on Saturday and the corresponding data for how much they spent on Monday, so that I would have the following data:

```
Saturday: [23.0,50.0,200.0]
Monday: [20.0,24,0,34.0]
```

How do I do this? I can do:

`SELECT cost FROM purchases WHERE Date=='Sat'` and `SELECT cost FROM purchases WHERE Date=='Mon'` but this doesn't seem very satisfactory because it depends on the order in which the database gives the result and a purchase may not have happened on both Saturday and Monday.

I investigated Joins and Unions for this purpose but they seem concerned with data from more than one table.

I'm sure there's a standard way to solve this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "correlate how much"

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have tried to clarify that in the question.

Comment: What if a customer didn't spend anything on one of those two days?

Comment: Then the query should return nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could join the table to itself; this would give you the data you want, but in the format

```
UserID, AmountSpentSat, AmountSpentMon
```

The SQL:

```
select p1.Customer, p1.cost as AmountMon, p2.cost as AmountSat
from purchases p1, purchases p2
where p1.customer = p2.customer
and p1.date = "Mon"
and p2.date = "Sat"
```

Here is a working sqlfiddle of it:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/367ef/1

Note I added a new customer (4) who only shopped on Sat and it works correctly.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me that SQLFiddle is a thing!  Excellent resource!